# SQL Server 2005 - Update column where DATEDIFF between two dates is minimum

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, minimum, date-difference

I have two tables, defined as following:

```
PTable:

[StartDate],    [EndDate],     [Type],     PValue
.................................................
2011-07-01      2011-07-07     001         5
2011-07-08      2011-07-14     001         10
2011-07-01      2011-07-07     002         15
2011-07-08      2011-07-14     002         20

TTable:

[Date],       [Type],     [TValue]
..................................
2011-07-01    001         11
2011-07-02    001         4
2011-07-03    001         0
2011-07-08    002         12
2011-07-09    002         12
2011-07-10    002         0
```

I want to update Tvalue column in TTable with the PValue in PTable, where [Date] in TTable is between [StartDate] and [EndDate] in PTable and DATEDIFF(DAY,TTable.[Date],PTable.[EndDate]) is minimum, AND PTable.Type = TTable.Type

The final TTable should look like this:

```
[Date],       [Type],     [TValue]
..................................
2011-07-01    001         11
2011-07-02    001         4
2011-07-03    001         5       --updated
2011-07-08    002         12
2011-07-09    002         12
2011-07-10    002         20       --updated
```

What I have tried is this:

```
UPDATE [TTable] 
        SET 
        TValue = T1.PValue
        FROM TTable
        INNER JOIN PTable T1 ON 
            [Date] BETWEEN T1.StartDate AND T1.EndDate 
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY,[Date],T1.EndDate) = 
              (SELECT MIN( DATEDIFF(DAY,TTable.[Date],T.EndDate)  ) 
              FROM PTable T WHERE  TTable.[Date] BETWEEN T.StartDate AND T.EndDate
             )
            AND
            T1.[Type] = TTable.[Type]
```

It gives me this error :
*"Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression."*

Later edit:

Considering TTable AS T and PTable AS P, the condition for update are:

```
1. T.Type = P.Type
2. T.Date BETWEEN P.StartDate AND P.EndDate
3. DATEDIFF(DAY,T.Date,P.EndDate) = minimum value of all DATEDIFFs WHERE P.Type = T.Type AND T.Date BETWEEN P.StartDate AND P.EndDate
```

**Later Edit 2:
Sorry, because I typed wrong the last row in PTable (2011-08-10  instead 2011-07-14), the final result was wrong.**

**I also managed to update in a simpler way, which I obviously should have tried from the start:**

```
UPDATE TTABLE 
        SET 
        TValue = T1.PValue
        FROM TTable
        INNER JOIN PTABLE T1 ON 
            [Date] = (SELECT TOP(1) MAX(Date) FROM [TTABLE] WHERE [Date] BETWEEN T1.StartDate AND T1.EndDate)
            AND
            T1.Type = [TTABLE].Type
```

Sorry about this.

Comment: Wait 1 min please, my query here is simplified. 1 moment to modify the original.

Comment: how do you know which rows to update from table TTable ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk The rows in TTable where [Date] is bewteen [StartDate] and [EndDate] in PTable AND the difference between [EndDate] from Ptable and [Date] in TTable is the smallest AND The Types in the tables are equal. The condition can be seen in my query, but i have an error..

Answer (score 0):

So you said something about "DATEDIFF(DAY,TTable.[Date],PTable.[EndDate]) is minimum" which confused me.  Itt would seem like if there a weekly entry per Type, then for a particular Date, Type combination it would ever only match one.  You might give this a try:

```
UPDATE TTABLE 
SET TValue = T1.PValue
FROM TTable
INNER JOIN PTABLE T1 ON T1.Type = [TTABLE].Type -- find row in PTable that the Date falls between
    and [Date] BETWEEN T1.StartDate AND T1.EndDate)
where 
    TValue = (  select MIN(TValue) -- finds the lowest TValue, 0 in example
                from TTable))
```

...updated...

So it appears I read the problem incorrectly the first time.  I had thought we update the TTable entries that have the lowest TValue.  Not sure how I got that impression.  Still seems like there needs to be a check for if it is 0?

```
UPDATE TTable 
SET TValue = T1.PValue
FROM TTable
INNER JOIN PTable T1 ON T1.Type = TTable.Type 
    and T1.EndDate = (
        SELECT top 1 EndDate 
        FROM PTable 
        WHERE Type=TTable.Type 
        ORDER BY abs(DATEDIFF(day,TTable.Date,PTable.EndDate)) desc)
WHERE 
    TValue = 0 -- only updating entries that aren't set, have a 0
```

This only works if there is one is one row in PTable with an EndDate of 7/7 or whatever for a given type.  If there are two entries for Type 001 with an end date of 7/7, then it will join to two entries.  Also if there is two entries that are equal distant from the date in question, so an EndDate of 7/7 and one of 7/13 are both 3 days from 7/10.  If the EndDates are all 7 days apart (weekly) you should be ok.

Comment: I said something about DATEDIFF because it was the first 'algorithm' which came up. At the end, because the DATEDIFF approach didn't work, I swiched to MAX([Date]) WHERE TTable.[Date] Between Ptable.StartDate AND Ptable.EndDate, which is basicaly the same thing. Anyway, your condition on where is not good, since TValue value doesn't matter, but the difference between dates ( the closest date to PTable.EndDate)

Comment: Seems odd.  So if I have Type 001 and a date of 7/8/2011, I should pull from the row that has an end date of 7/7, instead of the one that has a date range of 7/8 to 7/14?

Comment: No, you should pick from the range which include your date. And update only the row in TTable which has [Date] between StartDate and EndDate in PTable and closest to EndDate./n See my "Later edit 2" for the query.

Comment: Ah, so in the end you found the solution yourself, there is nothing to answer.